# App crashing after sleeping

Tags: java, android, crash, sleep

I'm currently following some video tutorials on Android development, and it's gone fine up until the 8th tutorial, we make a splash screen, and after 2 seconds it's supposed to go to the main application. The problem is, after 2 seconds, the screen goes black and the app crashes.

[Logcat Output](http://pastebin.com/tA78XFzn)

I followed the tutorial exactly as he did it, the only difference with mine is that I'm developing for 4.2 instead of 2.2.
I'm also using my Galaxy Note 2 instead of an emulator to test.

I did it all as he did, and pressed play, the app opened on my device and the splash screen was there for 2 seconds (i set it to 2000) and then the spinner (which I added) freezes. `The screen goes black, and then it crashes and says "Unfortunately, The Basic Series has stopped."`

I've tried both `sleep(2000)` and `Thread.sleep(2000)`.

Code for the `AndroidManifest.xml` and the `main.java` are [here](http://pastebin.com/VkJj4cUt)

If anyone is curious, this is the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4PqZKmQjjs) I was following.

Comment: You should never use `Thread.sleep` or anything like that on UI thread

Comment: ....well what should I use?

Comment: you have use, com.caius.thebasics.Menu ?

Comment: Try to change the name of the Activity from MENU to Menu and from MAIN to Main in your XML and java code. Unify the names.

Comment: @CaiusNewton-Smart if you're using sleep on UI thread, then you probably need to rething your activity logic. Use for example Handler and `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`

Comment: As I said, I started Android Development this afternoon. I have activity logic haha.

Comment: Menu.java is in src\com.caius.thebasics\menu.java

Comment: @yasserbn if I change them from MENU to Menu and MAIN to Main, when I try and run it on my device it says: 
http://pastebin.com/UYid7aQW

So it won't open at all now. It isn't in my app drawer either.

Answer (score 0):

1. avoid splash screens except if u really need them to do some preparation operations..
2. avoid Thread sleep otherwise you will face ANR crashes (use *post runnable with delay* instead)
3. avoid reading this hint: What is your activity class name? Menu, menu, MENU or uNeM?
4. not so good tutorial IMHO
5. not honorable mention: if u really want to do it in this (btw not recommended way) check video at 8:48 and try to add catch clause and log exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some initializations , use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , or a thread that upon completion will use [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) (so that it won't crash when doing UI operations).

If you need to just show the splash screen and close it after some time , use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) .

In all possible solutions , don't forget to cancel them upon onPause/onDestroy (depending on what you do/need) , so that if the user has left the app (exited or left it in the background) , it won't open up with the new activity when he resumes it (or worse , show it while it has gone to the background) .